# RestKit using nested JSON

Tags: json, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm having difficulty using RestKit to reach the data I need.

I'm attempting to reach the "jobs" data within this JSON file.

```
    {
      response: {
      accountResult: 1,
      accounts: [{
         userDetail: {
           idString: "de454657",
           idName: "alpha"
         },
         deptId: 245,
         jobs: [{
            jobId: "584349964",
            payHash: 566889,
            uniform: {
                color: "blue",
                tie: "red"},
            shoes: {
                color: "black",
                laces: "black"}
         },
         {
            jobId: "584349965",
            payHash: 566867,
            uniform: {
                color: "blue",
                tie: "red"},
            shoes: {
                color: "black",
                laces: "black"}
         },
         {
            jobId: "584349978",
            payHash: 566879,
            uniform: {
                color: "blue",
                tie: "red"},
            shoes: {
                color: "black",
                laces: "black"}
           }]
         }]
        }
    }
```

I can successfully map to the "accounts" level and map to items such as the "idName" and "deptID" but I can't determine how to reach the "jobs" data.

```
    keyPath:@"response.accounts.jobs"
```

Doesn't successfully work.  How does one do this?  I'm mapping to a class and not Core Data if that makes a difference on reaching this data.

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

**UPDATE - solution to reach data but not a solution to original question which asked if there is a method to directly reach the job data.**

I have the solution but still looking for anyone with a work around.

Since "jobs" is a JSON array within the "accounts" array I can parse the jobs by having two mappings - first to accounts and then to jobs.

```
    RKObjectMapping* accountMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Account class]];
    [accountMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"deptId":@"deptID"}];

    RKObjectMapping* jobMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Job class]];
    [jobMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"jobId":@"jobID"}];

    [accountMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"jobs"
                                                                              toKeyPath:@"job"
                                                                             withMapping:jobMapping]];
```

Is there a way to map directly to the jobs without reading in the accounts?  I only need a listing of all the Jobs in the file - no account info or their relationship is needed for my project.  Using above I can obviously read both data points and then use only the job data that I require - I hoped someone knew a way to avoid pulling in both (account & jobs) and a way to extract only jobs info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. Your solution with multiple mappings is the correct approach. If you don't need the 'container' object then you can discard it after the mapping is complete but you can't directly index into the array so you can't drill down to that level.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I figured if there was or wasn't some secret method that you would know.  Thanks @Wain.